# database design for multiple and all pepople

Tags: mysql

Assume I writing an email applicaiton.
Now I want to send some messages to specified person, some messages to multiple person, some messages to specified group and some to all members.
I am wondering in the best practice I have to treat every mail like a one instance mail, I mean I if I am sending mail to all I have to assign one record for every person or I can define a type field and from the code I must handle with codes.

Comment: Repeated data is usually a no-no.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mail Master table

MailID (PK)
Mail content 

Emp Master table

EmpID (PK)
EmpName


Mail-Employee Mapping table

Mail-Employee_ID (auto increament id PK)
MailID (FK)
EmployeeID (FK)

Group_Master table

GroupID (auto increament PK)
GroupName 

Group_Employee_Mapping table

Group_Employee_ID (auto increament)
GroupID (FK)
EmployeeID (FK)
(GroupID+Employee are unique so Composite PK)
```

I think tables and their roles are self explanatory.

Some rule for Group Master:-

`Group_Employee_Mapping` is predefined in system :you have already mapped all employee and its group in this table.One employee can belong to many group .

If Group='All' don't store "All" employee in `Group_Employee_Mapping` Table.As this is unnecessary

If user select "All" select all employee from Employee Table ,send them mail and store each employee and mailid in "`Mail-Employee Mapping`" table

If user select any specific group then select those employee from `Group_Employee_Mapping` table,send them mail and store them in M`ail-Employee Mapping`